# Integration: find the shaded area in diagram bound by the curves $y=\sin(2x)$ and $y=\cos(x)$ for: $\frac{-\pi}{2} \le x \le \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, solution-verification, problem-solving, trigonometric-integrals

> Find the shaded area bound by the curves $y=\sin(2x)$ and $y=\cos(x)$
> for:
>
> $$\frac{-\pi}{2} \le x \le \frac{\pi}{2}$$

[image]

What I have tried so far:

**For part (a):**

area under $y=\cos(x)$ is given by

$$\int_{\pi/2}^{-\pi/2} \cos(x)dx=-2⇒2 \,\text{units}^2$$

area under $y=\sin(2x)$ is given by

$$\int_{0}^{-\pi/2} \sin(2x)dx=1$$

$$\int_{\pi/2}^{0} \sin(2x)dx=-1$$

total = $2\, \text{units}^2$

Would the fact that they are the same area, be helpful in finding the solution? So both areas under the curves for the given domain $\frac{-\pi}{2} \le x \le\frac{\pi}{2}$ are $2\, \text{units}^2$, but I'm still unsure how to proceed from here for both part (a) and (b).

Any hints would be much appreciated!

This is from a Year 12 Methods book.

Comment: For (a): It is easy to show that the two curves intersect at $x=\pi/6$. Now, the area you are looking for is $$
\int_{\pi /6}^{\pi /2} {\sin (2x)dx}  - \int_{\pi /6}^{\pi /2} {\cos (x)dx} .
$$ Can you see why? You can deal with (b) in a similar manner.

Comment: @Gary, yes! I missed that part - thank you very much :)

Comment: @Gary, I was wondering if $\frac{π}{2}$ and $\frac{π}{6}$ are the other way around (since it is *from* $\frac{π}{6}$ to $\frac{π}{2}$)?...please correct me if I'm wrong? Or does it not make a difference?

Comment: It is in the correct order, think about it again. What is the meaning of that difference of two integrals?

Comment: Oh, I see..thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The two curves cross at $x=-\pi/6$, so the shades area id given as
$$A=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/6} [\cos x-\sin 2x] dx+\int _{\pi/6}^{\pi/2} [\sin 2x -\cos x] dx=\frac{9}{4}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{5}{2}.$$